# Bigcommerce - Implementing custom code that runs on server-side to create multiple versions of page for a product?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm new to Bigcommerce but experienced with web app development. I have a need to make customizations to a Bigcommerce store where I need to implement custom logic that runs on the server-side which affects the output in the UI by deciding which page to serve. For example, I want to have different versions of a product page for different locations. I want each version to have a static URL, however, for SEO purposes. I need to implement logic in the server-side to do something like detect user location based on IP and then determine which of the product version pages to serve. I realize I can do this with JavaScript but I don't want to as I don't think that would work as well for SEO.

I have looked over their API and templating briefly but am not seeing a real way that this is possible. Wondering if anyone can guide me in the right direction or is Bigcommerce too simplified to allow this sort of customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have server side access on Bigcommerce. The only would to do this would be client side with javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw this now, I did come to the same conclusion, so ended up dropping bigcommerce, I realized it's not a good tool for someone who wants to do a lot of customization